# Sharding with sequelize.js

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, sharding

This is a question about implementing sharding through Sequelize.

Currently I have a sharded databases which I need to support in my app, but this gives me a lot of trouble. I tried to use your framework but did not succeed. I will explain the architecture:
Suppose I have 3 databases, one is "meta db" which stores map of user data (i.e. on which shard the user data is) and two shards with equal structure storing user data.

```
var MetaUser = sequelize.define("MetaUser", {
        shardId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10), allowNull: false }
    }
};

var User = sequelize.define("User", {
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        about: { type: DataTypes.STRING(2048) },
    }
};
```

The problem is - all this databases can be on different servers so I need to create 3 different connections, or 3 different sequelize instances. And the following looks like (suppose dbConfig is read from json file and models are described in isolated files):

```
var metaConnection = new Sequelize(dbConfig.meta.database,
    dbConfig.meta.username,
    dbConfig.meta.password,
    dbConfig.meta.options);
module.exports.dbMeta = metaConnection;
var user1Connection = new Sequelize(dbConfig.shard1.database,
    dbConfig.shard1.username,
    dbConfig.shard1.password,
    dbConfig.shard1.options);
module.exports.dbUser1 = user1Connection;
var user2Connection = new Sequelize(dbConfig.shard2.database,
    dbConfig.shard2.username,
    dbConfig.shard2.password,
    dbConfig.shard2.options);
module.exports.dbUser2 = user2Connection;

module.exports.MetaUser = metaConnection.import(__dirname + "/models/MetaUser");
module.exports.User1 = user1Connection.import(__dirname + "/models/User");
module.exports.User2 = user2Connection.import(__dirname + "/models/User");
```

This gives me problems:

1. I cannot reference one model from another in model's module since
   I don't have access to other model's connection in this model.
2. I want to use User model in my project, and have no need in MetaUser,
   but I have to handle User through MetaUser in order to calculate
   necessary shard connection.

If someone experienced similar problems, follow me to the solution, please.